# Enter Key To Download Product

Tags: javascript, html, key, product

I'm a game developer who is creating a website for his project. I want players to enter a key before downloading my game from this website. I am trying to use HTML and JavaScript to make this possible. I haven't done something like this before and would like some help writing the code for it. Could someone please help me out? If so, that'd be a big help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're going to need some server-side code otherwise your game would be insanely easy to pirate.

Comment: Enter a key? Not going to be secure if it is on the clientside.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a backend server to do to this, it will test if the key is valid, if not it won't download. If it is valid it will download.

Here is the most basic authentication that you can do.

I would recommend using a better secret key to test for validation, such as a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

**download.php**

```
<?php
// This is your key.
// The value can come from anywhere such as a database.
// It could also just be a string like it is in this example.
$key = 'my-secret-key';

// If the user doesn't enter the valid key don't allow the download to take place.
// We do this by just exiting from the file.
if($_POST['key'] != $key) exit;

// This is the path to the original file.
// It will be used to gather information below.
$file = '/path/to/file.exe';

// Setup the headers.
// This will allow the browser to do what it needs with the file.
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"my_game.exe\"");
header("Content-Type: application/x-msdownload");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

// Reads the file and outputs it to the stream.
readfile($file);
```

Next you need a form that posts to the **download.php** file, with the key that you can test. The form is fairly basic just an input to enter a key, and a submit button.

**index.html**

```
<form action="/path/to/download.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="key" placeholder="Enter the secret key" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

Comment: This is a good example considering the question, but just for the OP's sake, a better solution would be to generate a token for a specific user. That way no one can just copy their token and send it to whoever wants it.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I had that in the answer, but then removed it